# Delete records from a database based upon selection in a datagridview

Tags: database, datagridview

Can you please help me with this one.

Items are deleted from the datagridview but not from the db.

Part of my code:

```
private void btn_TaBortSpelare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand delCmd;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
            delCmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from Spelare where Namn="+ Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value) +"", conn);
            daRegMedl.DeleteCommand = delCmd;
            daRegMedl.Update(dsFotboll, tbl_RegMedl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like This

```
private void btn_TaBortSpelare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand delCmd;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
            delCmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from Spelare where 
           Namn='"+ textBox1.Text.Trim +"'", conn);
            daRegMedl.DeleteCommand = delCmd;
            daRegMedl.Update(dsFotboll, tbl_RegMedl);
        }
    }
```

Change `Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value)` to `textBox1.Text`. Because first you remove the row after that add the that value in query that's not work so replace item.cells[2].value to textbox1.text in your query

Comment: It make sense, I try your code (except for that I don't have ".Trim" becase otherwise I am getting a compiler error about the operand + can not be applied to string and methodGroup). Actually the code compiles and I get the application running, the seleted record is removed from the datagridview but still in the database. I am having an access db and datatype of "Namn" is Text.

Comment: @user3518904 Now look at my code i add ' in this `Namn='"+ textBox1.Text.Trim +"'"` because of you say Namn is text data type that only now try this